# react-native - navigator.geolocation.watchPosition not firing when expected - android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, react-native

I'm making an app with react-native that needs to update users location based on the distance they moved. I'm using `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` for the event listener but it's not behaving as expected. Here's my test code :

```
export default class geoApp extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        lastPos: 'unknown',
    }
    this.watchID = null;
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        (pos) => {
            const lastPos = JSON.stringify(pos.coords)
            this.setState({ lastPos: lastPos });
        },
        (error) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error))
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0, distanceFilter: 1 }
    );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                {this.state.lastPos}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried removing the options object or just changing the data but nothing works.

If I don't put the options object the callback will fire ony once and usally it will be after 20 seconds , if I leave the options object as is it won't even fire.

I thought it would be because of the `maximumAge` but I tried to put different data in it and nothing worked.

I even tried `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation` and wrapping it inside a `setInterval`but it returns me always the same information.

Any help would be appreceated, thank you !

Notes: I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` in my manifest

react and react-native versions are as follows:
`"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.47.2"`

I am trying to run on a android Huawei P9 lite.